# Simple rich text editor in Text widget?

Tags: plugins, widgets, wysiwyg

I've seen a few plugins that add rich text editing to the default "Text" Widget. However, all of the ones I've tested are either too complicated (or try to do too much) or don't work properly with the latest WP versions.

I'm just looking for a simple rich text toolbar with a minimal feature set (basic formatting and lists), image upload and hyperlink tool.

Ideally, I'd like to find one that does not require a separate window to handle rich text. Just a simple tab to switch between html and wysiwyg.

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: "image upload" is anything but simple

Comment: I can imagine, but aren't the bits already in place in WP core? I'd take it without, but it would be nice to have. Not a must by any means though, since the media manager is only a few clicks away. Image selection from an existing repository would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never found one that was reliable and/or not a huge resource/memory drain. :( I ended up using the very handy "[Page in Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-in-widget/)" plugin instead - it has the advantage of all the functionality of a regular editable page and your widget content won't accidentally get wiped, which has happened to me far too often.

Sorry not to have the perfect solution. Will check back to see if others do! :)

Michelle

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try the [Black Studio TinyMCE Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/) plugin, which adds a WYSIWYG text widget based on the standard TinyMCE WordPress editor.

Comment: Note: I did not mention I am the plugin's author, so if you decide to try it, your feedback would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I just deactivated and deleted your plugin because it wasn't working for me for some reason. Whenever I try to type into the Visual tab, it won't let me. It won't let me insert media as well. I looked at the HTML tab and it seems to work. Your plugin is glitching for some reason. Maybe it needs an update?

Comment: @CheeseCake If you're experiencing issues with the plugin, please check the [FAQ](https://wordpress.org/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/faq/) and post to [support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/black-studio-tinymce-widget).

Answer (score 1):

I've started to use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wysiwyg-widgets/ (WYSIWYG Widgets) and it seems to work pretty well. I ran into a few weird glitches with it initially - but clicking "save" on the widget each time before editing it again seems to get rid of the random glitches I was seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Spots plugin, it gives you exactly what you want, adds post shortcodes, and allows you to reuse content

[image]

You can find it here:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/spots/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with this line

```
the_editor( 'Content to be in the editor', $field_name );
```

Answer (score -1):

Just want to give some feedback on my experience trying to find a good, reliable WYSIWYG widget editor.  I've tried 5 different ones in the past 2 hours, and 4 of them all have issues.

The one that works best is the Black Studio TinyMCE editor mentioned above, so Marcochiesi, thanks for creating a nice simple editor! It works great!

The others had strange glitches and just didn't do the job.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not [an answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer).